# Refreshing the page when the user resizes the window

Tags: window-resize

How can I automatically refresh the page (with JS/jQuery) whenever the user resizes the window ?

(it must sound like a weird thing to do but I have a good reason to want this : in summary, Dailymotion videos cannot be resized by JS dynamically as YouTube videos can, but their size can be set by JS based on the window size)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onresize = function(){window.location.reload();}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers the *resize* event is triggered continually while resizing, so you need a [debounced](http://paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/) [event](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/). When that event goes off, there are [many ways](http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html) to refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Paul Irish's code but sometimes the page reloads 3 or 4 times in a row instead of 1 :/